# Converting readline's ReadlineBytes to Strings

Tags: rust, readline

I am trying to create a program with a readline-powered command prompt.

I am using [this](https://crates.io/crates/readline) crate.

```
readline = "0.0.11"
```

This is the example from the repository. (Link to repository is on the crate's page.)

```
#![cfg(not(test))]

extern crate readline;

use readline::readline;

use std::ffi::CString;
use std::io::Write;
use std::io;

fn main() {
    let prompt = CString::new("user> ").unwrap();
    let mut stdout = io::stdout();
    while let Ok(s) = readline(&prompt) {
        stdout.write_all(s.to_bytes()).unwrap();
        stdout.write_all(b"\n").unwrap();
    }
    stdout.write_all(b"\n").unwrap();
}
```

I am trying to convert `s` from a `readline::common::ReadlineBytes` to a `std::string::String` so I can `match` on it like this.

```
while let Ok(s) = readline(&prompt){
    let command = str::from_utf8(&s.to_bytes()).unwrap();
    match command {
        "exit"  => std::process::exit,
        "again" => break,
        _ => println!("error")
    }
    println!("{}", command);
}
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
main.rs:18:9: 22:10 error: match arms have incompatible types:
 expected `fn(i32) -> ! {std::process::exit}`,
    found `()`
(expected fn item,
    found ()) [E0308]
main.rs:18         match command {
main.rs:19             "exit"  => std::process::exit,
main.rs:20             "again" => break,
main.rs:21             _ => println!("error")
main.rs:22         }
note: in expansion of while let expansion
main.rs:16:5: 24:6 note: expansion site
main.rs:18:9: 22:10 help: run `rustc --explain E0308` to see a detailed explanation
main.rs:21:18: 21:35 note: match arm with an incompatible type
main.rs:21             _ => println!("error")
                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
note: in expansion of while let expansion
main.rs:16:5: 24:6 note: expansion site
error: aborting due to previous error
```

Comment: A few of us have written readline wrappers. Mine https://github.com/shaleh/readline is much easier to use for the common cases.

Comment: @SeanPerry, did you mean https://github.com/shaleh/rust-readline? That does look a lot simpler. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Match arms all have to return the same type. Look at your error message again:

```
main.rs:18:9: 22:10 error: match arms have incompatible types:
 expected `fn(i32) -> ! {std::process::exit}`,
    found `()`
(expected fn item,
    found ()) [E0308]
```

One of your match arms is returning `()`, the other is returning the type `fn(i32) -> ! {std::process::exit}` — a function.

Look at your code:

```
"exit"  => std::process::exit,
```

You aren't *calling* `exit`, you are just returning a reference to it.